# Why doesn't manpage show the available options?

Tags: terminal, man

When I open a manual in bash in Linux Mint 17.1, e.g. `man man`, the available options are not shown.

[image: Screenshot]

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: can't you provide a text copy/paste ?

Comment: Looks like bold isn't working? What terminal are you using? Have you have any changes to the settings that might be related?

Comment: Looks like you are setting a color incorrectly: do you export `LESS_TERMCAP` values in one of your shell initialization files?

Comment: These are not the default settings for gnome-terminal. What did you change?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Mikel
For some reason the color for bold was set to black in my terminal profile. 
After switching to `Same as text colour` everything works perfectly.